# Button in Every xml.avoid writing code in every xml

Tags: android, xml, button

I have 5 xmls.in every xml i am creating 10 buttons.my question is that is there anyways to avoid writing same code for button in every xml.in every xml there are different elements also present.only that 10 buttons are common in every xml.for example:

```
xml1-> button 1 button2   button3 button4(present at top) textbox
xml2-> button 1 button2   button3 button4(present at top) editbox
xml3-> button 1 button2   button3 button4(present at top) imagebutton
xml4-> button 1 button2   button3 button4(present at top) listview
```

its not my original code

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</relativelayout>
```

Comment: also i need reuse  my java class.is it possible.if i have 10 classes which are using this xml.i want to avoid writing this code everytime like button b1=findviewbyid(r.id.b1);(in all 10 classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a button in one xml and then use include tag in the layout's that you want.

```
<include android:id="@+id/b1" layout="@layout/button_layout" />
```

Here's a blog by Romain Guy on the same

http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/

Comment: @MycareerId In the above `button_layout` is a layout with the button. You can include that in your xml

Comment: it s working but can u tell me if is there any possibility for reuseing of code( i mean in every class i need to write findViewById(R.id.button1)).

Comment: @MycareerId When you include you define a id for the same. you can use that. Every inflate you need to use `findViewById`

Answer (score 2):

You can create an xml with the 10 buttons that are repeated (if they always appear together):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
     ...
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
    ...
    />
...
</relativelayout>
```

And then, include this xml in the different layouts:

```
<include layout="@layout/ten_buttons"/>
```

But if the 10 buttons are included in different ways, then you should create a xml for each one: button1.xml, button2.xml, button3.xml, etc. and include them separately:

```
<include layout="@layout/button1"/>
<include layout="@layout/button2"/>
<include layout="@layout/button3"/>
```